# Given an object in python, can I somehow leave one attribute empty?

Tags: python, object, attributes

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, _one, _two):
        self.one = _one
        self.two = _two


t = test(1, 2)

print(t.one)
print(t.two)
```

let's say, for some reason, i want to create an instance of class test, that only has the first attribute, leaving the second as null oder whatever. Is there any possibility to do so without creating a different class? If possible, I'd like to do it without inheritance.

Comment: `def __init__(self, _one, _two=None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your goal correctly, you can use default paramater:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, _one = None, _two =None):
        self.one = _one
        self.two = _two


t = test(1, 2)

print(t.one) #1
print(t.two) #2

t = test(_one=1)

print(t.one) #1
print(t.two) #None

t = test(_two=2)

print(t.one) #None
print(t.two) #2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could pass `None` to the constructor.

```
t1 = test(1, None)

t2 = test(None, 2)
```

Just be careful to check for `None` before doing arithmetic with the attributes, because that will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default` value, like that:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, _one, _two=None):
        self.one = _one
        self.two = _two

test(_one=1) #should be fine, will assign None to `_two`
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use None?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, _one=None, _two=None):
        self.one = _one
        self.two = _two
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it. just do:

```
class test:
def __init__(self, _one=None, _two=None):
    self.one = _one
    self.two = _two
```

now you can create objects like this:

```
t = test(1, 2)
t1 = test(3)
print(t.one, t.two)
print(t1.one, t1.two)
```

output:

```
(1, 2) (3, None)
```

the problem with this method is that when you do `t1 = test(3)`, `self.one` will be `3` and `self.two` will be `None`. but what if you want `self.two` to be initialized and `self.one` to be `None`?

to solve this use `t1 = test(_two=3)`. now when you do

```
t = test(1, 2)
t1 = test(_two=3)
print(t.one, t.two)
print(t1.one, t1.two)
```

the output will be `(1, 2) (None, 3)`